# Is it possible to communicate between multiple threads from multiple instances of the same program?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, multiple-instances

I'm making a desktop java program that multiple people from different computers will be accessing at once because it is on a shared drive. The program writes user input to an excel file, so I was wondering if it is possible for different instances of the same program to be able to do that, or would I have to create another thread each time someone opens the program?
I don't know how to use threads.

Comment: Each user will be running there own process, locally to their own machine context.  Multi threads don't come into play, but if they are trying to update the same file then you have issues, as it might be possible for two people to write content simultaneously, creating corruptions in the data...this is why we have database servers...

Comment: [FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html)?

Comment: @DavidPostill FileLock is OS dependent and I have use cases where it's failed across networked drives...just saying ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thats good to know, have you documented your failed use cases anywhere?

Comment: Note that each user will be running their own java process on their own machine - so multiple threads will be running, but they'll be running on separate JVMs. The term "multi-threaded" typically means multiple threads running on the same JVM.

Comment: If this is a graphical program, you're going to have to learn to use threads.

Comment: @DavidPostill We have a client who uses 5 laptops to access a single file on a shared drive over a wireless network. These laptops come into and out of range of the wireless network.  We have constant issues with the file they access been corrupted and it only occurs when two or more people try and update there details to the file, despite my predecessor (who wrote the program) using `FileLock`. Each time it occurs, I just rattle of `Socket`/server, web service, SQL database server...but no one wants to do that cause that would require actually designing a solution...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would use an online database, but this application is not allowed to have internet access, so I have to do this locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that.  If they all write to the same Excel file on the shared drive, you will have to implement some form of locking on the file, so that the file is not corrupted by multiple instances of the application writing to it at once.  If they are using the application to write a new Excel file on their own machines, and the shared drive is just being used as an application server from which they can find your application, you don't even have to do that.

You don't have to worry about threading in this case, as each instance of the application can be singly threaded.  It's a case of multiprocessing rather than multithreading.

Comment: I just thought of something else. I had originally planned on making them all write to one excel file in the shared drive, but now instead, I think I could make each application create a new text file in the shared drive, and then later I would run another program that would get the text from each of those files and then adds them into the excel file.